# libGDX newbie confusion

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

I am a former iOS developer who would like to start developing cross-platform mobile games. libGDX looked like a promising engine to use. I have a few questions for you guys just so I know if I am on a right track. I know this is a little off topic, but please bear with me.

How troublesome and time consuming is it to transport a game made for iOS platform to Android platform or vice versa?

Does libGDX offer an editor into which I can drag objects and run the simulation without the need to run it on device everytime you want to see if everything works?

Which version of Java does libGDX support? Should I learn Java 8 or should  I learn 7?

Comment: Question is not opinion based.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what libgdx is, it is no editor/engine, just a framework. For example it "supports" no java language (it is written in java) the support depends on the platform (where java 6 is the current smallest "default").

Comment: Oh I see. so you have rewrite a game for each platform? objective C for iOS and Java for Android?

Comment: No you got me wrong. You write in java, but it is not libgdx that needs to support a java version but the devices it runs on. I don't know about IOS, but libgdx uses robovm by default, since I don't use that can't help you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your game in LibGDX, there is no need for transporting or code modification, gradle will do all the neccessary work for you when compiling. You just must consider different devices resolution, interacting device like touch, gamepad, keyboard and mouse. All you have to do is to compile for required platform which can be android, windows, html and IOS (for compiling to IOS you must be on OSX).

If you want editor like unity, libgdx doesn't provide that. But there some third party editors for Physics, Body and tiled maps. It's good for 2D games, but can be hard to make 3D ones.

Java version doesn't differ, you learn 6 you can code in 7. the new version just have some new programming features which is provided by means of new syntax or libraries. Actually android is a subset of java 6 library and syntax of 7 as API 14+, I believe the same is true for LibGDX. So you write your game using java 6 syntax but with libraries provided by LibGDX.

The best IDE you can code in is Intellij Idea which it's free version fully support LibGDX coding in windows and OSX.

EDIT -------------------------

some editor and tools:

- [R.U.B.E](https://www.iforce2d.net/rube/) nice editor for box2d (physics)
- [PhysicsEditor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor)
- [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)
- [Normal Map Editor](https://www.codeandweb.com/spriteilluminator)
- [2D and 3D particle editors and other built in tools](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html)
- [Some map editors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/225/tools-for-creating-2d-tile-based-maps)

Actually there are a lot of other tools, it depends of the game you want to make.

Comment: Thank you! Can you point out what third party editors you know?

Comment: @krompir2 I added some tools.

Comment: Thank you! I think I am good to go

Answer (score 1):

If you make a game for iOS using libGDX, porting it to android won't be much of a problem. Unless you use a lot of platform specific code, you pretty much won't have to change any of your code. And even if you do, making the game support both platforms shouldn't be too big of a problem.

LibGDX doesn't have an editor. As Pinkie Swirl mentioned, it is not an engine like Unity or Construct, it is a Java framework building on LWJGL. There are some tools for creating your levels, like [overlap2d](http://overlap2d.com/), but those won't help you do the actual programming. As for testing the games on your computer, apart from just running the game as a normal PC game, there are also emulators available for both Android and iOS (though the iOS one might only be available on OS X)

The Java version you use doesn't matter much, as LibGDX supports all Java versions from 6 and up. Be careful however, some devices might not have the newest version of Java so you probably shouldn't use the new features in Java 8 (you probably won't need to anyway).